# Various plugins (such as Kotlin) are marked incompatible with Android Studio 3.4 Beta 1

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-3.4

For both the Kotlin and Material Theme plugins I get the message that they are "incompatible with the current android studio version." Kotlin files fail to be read as anything other than plaintext, and I get a notification saying, "Plugin supporting feature (Facet[kotlin-language]) is currently not installed."

What's going wrong here? Is anyone else having this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after just installing the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA. I realized that there are some versions listed on their website that weren't compatible. I went to the home menu `IntelliJ IDEA` -> `Check for Updates...` and realized there were new Kotlin updates, even though I thought I had just installed the latest Kotlin version on my prior version of IntelliJ a few minutes before. After installing the Kotlin updates, everything worked again.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin

[image]